# How to center a burger icon vertically inside a div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a navigation menu that contains a burger icon made with 3 `<span>` that is inside another elements :

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #df0024;
  padding: 1% 0;
}

.tog {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 6%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
}


/*This is the div that contain the burger 3 layers*/

#nav-icon {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -moz-fill-available;
  height: -o-fill-available;
  height: fill-available;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*/The style of each of the burger icon 3 layers*/
#nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3.1vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 12px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="" alt='Logo' /></a>
  </div>
  <div id='tog' class="tog">
    <label for="toggle" id='nav-icon'>
        <div class='icon-container'>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span> 
        </div>          
           </label>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How to center the `#nav-icon span` inside the `#nav-icon` vertically ? All I want is centering the burger icon so I don't care of changing the other elements style that contain the burger icon.

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to it

Comment: @ShaharGalukman , to which element ?

Comment: Have you tried using `margin: 0 auto;` on `#nav-icon span`

Comment: @Joe The `#nav-icon span`, or their container.

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak a lot to make this work, but I used a nice vertical-centering trick I know involving `top: 50%;` plus `transition: translateY(-50%);`. If you apply those to a child div then it will be vertically centered within a sized parent (the parent should also have position `relative` or `absolute`).

I applied these styles to the `.icon-container` in your code.

```css
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #df0024;
    padding: 1% 0;
}

.tog {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 6%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
}

/*This is the div that contain the burger 3 layers*/
#nav-icon{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-container {
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}


 #nav-icon span{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 9px;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
          <a  href="#"><img src="" alt='Logo'/></a>
    </div>
    <div id='tog' class="tog">
          <label for="toggle" id='nav-icon'>
             <div class='icon-container'>
                 <span></span>
                 <span></span>
                 <span></span>  
             </div>                               
          </label>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing against flex, you may also drop the absolute positionning.

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;/* vertical-centering */
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #df0024;
  padding: 1% 0;
  /* DEMO PURPOSE ONLY to show vertical centering */
  transition:0.25s;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%);
}
.navbar:hover {height:200px;}
  /* end -- DEMO PURPOSE ONLY to show vertical centering */
nav a {
/* demo purpose , useless about centering  */
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  color: white;
}



.tog {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin-left: auto;/* goes all the way to the right side */
}


/*This is the div that contain the burger 3 layers*/

#nav-icon {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*The style of each of the burger icon 3 layers*/

#nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 0.25em;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="" alt='Logo' /></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#">another link ? </a>
  <div id='tog' class="tog">
    <label for="toggle" id='nav-icon'>
     <div class='icon-container'>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span> 
     </div>          
    </label>
  </div>
</nav>
```